# React native unable to load scripts automatically appear disappear in android

Tags: react-native

I am running **$react-native run-android**. it is working properly, also, I am able to see the changes on android emulator. I have created 3 components and also tested it on android device.

But now, suddenly, it is asking me **unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'** Also, I have reverted the changes and started but still I am seeing this error.

After serching on internet, I performed,
1. npm start
2. react-native start
3. adb kill-server and adb start-server
but all in vein.

Last, I found and performed below commands,
**$ mkdir android/app/src/main/assets
$ react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
$ react-native run-android**

I am able to resolve above error with above commands, but now, when I am changing App.js file, it is not getting reflected on emulator. please help.

My steps performed: http://sachin4java.blogspot.in/2017/12/unable-to-load-scripts-from-assets.html

Comment: Did you try resetting the bundler cache? `react-native start --reset-cache`

Comment: for $ react-native start --reset-cache, I am getting below error, 'ERROR  Metro Bundler can't listen on port 8081'.Also tried below commands but No LUCK.   \n sachin@sachin-E470:~/react-native/aaaa$ lsof -i -P|grep 8081
node       5026 sachin   23u  IPv6 2053427      0t0  TCP *:8081 (LISTEN)
sachin@sachin-E470:~/react-native/aaaa$ sudo kill -9 5026
[sudo] password for sachin: 
sachin@sachin-E470:~/react-native/aaaa$ react-native start --reset-cache
sachin@sachin-E470:~/react-native/aaaa$ react-native run-android

Comment: You installed a `--dev false` app on your emulator. Try uninstalling it before running `react-native run-android`

Comment: where to change this '--dev false' setting in react-native app

Comment: I meant, the app that is installed on your emulator now is not in dev mode - look at the `bundle` command you typed. Uninstall the app - `adb uninstall your.package.name` and then `run-android` again.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many things as found on internet, but no one worked.
I removed installed node, NPM and nodejs
I installed it again with : http://sachin4java.blogspot.in/2017/12/react-native-setup-in-ubuntu-16.html

Then I installed in new version in Android studio AVD image named 'Nexus_5X_API_26(AVD)'. 
Now, I am able to see the code changes reflecting and red error screen gone.